# How improve select query performance in 10M+ records table?

Tags: sql, oracle, database-performance

I have a table with more than 10 million rows, and I use simple queries with bind variables (in my case I can't search by primary key id).

The table looks like this:

```
Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   Col5   Col6
```

and the queries is like

```
select distinct col1  
from table ;

select distinct col2 
where col1 = :bind ;

select distinct col3 
where col1 = :bind1 and col2 = :bind2 ;
.
.

select distinct col6 
where col1 = :bind1 and col2 = :bind2 and col3 = :bind3
  and col4 = :bind4 and col5 = :bind5
```

The results of all of these queries are not large - less than 100 records at MAX - but the performance is too slow .

How to improve it ?

Comment: You haven't mentioned anything about indexes at all, so start here: https://use-the-index-luke.com/

Comment: If there are fewer than 100 distinct `col1` values in a table, I'd be very suspicious of your first query.  There should be no reason to hit a 10 million row table for those rows, your data model really ought to have a lookup table with just those 100 rows in it that you could hit.  Depending on what these columns represent, you may want more than a few lookup tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an index on `(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)`.  This can be used for all the queries:

```
create index idx_t_5 on t(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5);
```

If that is not possible and the columns have the same type, then you can use a lateral join in Oracle 12c+ to combine this into a single query:

```
select distinct which, col
from t cross apply
     (select 'col1' as which, t.col1 as col from dual union all
      select 'col2', t.col2 from dual where t.col2 = :bind2 union all
      . . .
     ) t
where col1 = :bind1;
```

This will scan the table only once, which be a performance improvement.

Comment: ok , but if want to select 2 columns how will the syntax be ?

Comment: its really complicated could you elaborate please ?

Comment: @osfar While it's a bit more complicated that your typical select, it's quite useful. Yet, you really, really need to get the right indexes in place. A correct index can see speed improvements of hundreds of times. In the past I saw creating an index on a 10M+ table reduce query time from over 1 hour to under 1 second.

Comment: @osfar . . . If you wanted to select two columns, you would have a different question.  But you can easily add more columns into the lateral join.

Comment: @ Aleks G  how to make the perfect index for my case ?

Answer (score 0):

In general, build an index this way:

1. Include all the `WHERE` columns that are tested against a constant with `=`.  (All of your examples so far meet this criterium.)  The columns can be in any order.
2. (This is optimal.)  Include the `SELECT` items at the end of the `INDEX`, any order.  This makes the index "covering" (unless it is more complex than described).
3. Note that extra columns on the end are a slight burden, but no harm.

The "composite" `INDEX(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6)` happens to match both of these 'rules'  If you have some `SELECT` this is a bit different, show it to us; we may be able to help you build another index for it.